# MYSQL: doing a select to filter using the ID of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I really dont know how to ask this so i will resume and go to the point.
I have 2 tables.

(Im using Wordpress so you may know the tables)

Table 1 = **wp_users** (contains `id` column and `display_name` nickname)

Table 2 = **wp_simple_login_log** (contains `uid` column wich is the ID of the user, should be the same `ID` in wp_users. It also contains `time` column where the last log is recorded in this format(2015-3-11))

What table 2 do is save the date of the last log of each user. Table 1 have all the users of my site.

I want to select all the users that had logged in the last 3 months.
This is what i thought of doing.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_simple_login_log`
INNER JOIN `wp_users` ON wp_users.id = wp_simple_login_log.uid
```

That works, but it brings ALL the logs, thats good because i never specified the "range" that i wanted.

So i added at the end:

`WHERE time '%2015%'`

which obviously didn't work, so here I am, any ideas?

I want to filter the logs of the last 3 months where the "display_name" column contains an "@" (I also need to filter those users with emails on their nickname)

Comment: select ... from users ...  where EXISTS (select 1 from login_log ... etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is stored as a date, then you would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_simple_login_log l INNER JOIN
       wp_users u
       ON u.id = l.uid
WHERE l.time >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 month);
```

If it is stored as a string, then do an explicit conversion:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_simple_login_log l INNER JOIN
       wp_users u
       ON u.id = l.uid
WHERE date(l.time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 month);
```

For the YYYY-MM-DD format, conversion can just use the `date()` function.

Comment: Amazing, this worked like a charm. Thank you Gordon!